# SQL - Min() on a Daily Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull some specific information from an access control database.
I have a query providing results spanning several days. For a specific day, I need to get the first record of each person for that specific day. I have totally muddled the entire bit, hence my questions

This is the code used to pull the initial query

```
Select
    Message.TimeStamp_SPM,
    Message.FirstName,
    Message.LastName,
    Message.CardNumber,
    Message.MessageDescription,
    Message.Description,
    Department.Description As Description1
From
    Message Inner Join
    CardHolder On CardHolder.CardHolderID = Message.CardHolderID Inner Join
    Department On CardHolder.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID
Where
    Message.TimeStamp_SPM > Convert(datetime,'2021-03-02',120) And
    Message.TimeStamp_SPM < Convert(datetime,'2021-03-03',120) And
    Message.Description Not Like '%Truck%'
```

From this query I need to display the obtain the first record of each person for that specific date. Any advice on the most efficient way to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Could you please add a data sample and the desired result to illustrate your problem? Also tagging your specific RDBMS (and version) will help to come up with the right answer.

Comment: What is a "person"?  How is that defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From this query I need to display the obtain the first record of each person for that specific date.

Assuming "person" is `CardHolderId`, then include that in your query.  You can then use window functions to get the most recent record for each `CardHolderId`:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here with CardHolderId>
     )
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CardHolderID order by TimeStamp_SPM desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum = 1;
```